# Calculation of extinction coeffcient of GFP

Tags: molecular-biology

I want to convert the absorption of a protein into concentration. Hence ı need to calculate the extinction coefficient of the protein (GFP). ı found the formula (nTrp)5500+(nTyr)1490 on the internet but not able to use it since ı dont understand what n in front of the amino acids stand for and how ı reach to the n value

Answer (score 3):

Only the number ("n") of the aromatic amino acids Tryptophan (Trp) and Tyrosin (Tyr) in your protein contribute significantly to its absorption at 280 nm (and Cystein (Cys), albeit to a lesser extend), see also [here](https://tools.thermofisher.com/content/sfs/brochures/TR0006-Extinction-coefficients.pdf).

You could retrieve the protein's amino acid sequence from uniprot (see GFP [here](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P42212)). Looking through the GFP sequence, one can identify n=11 (4.6%) Tyr and n=1 (0.4%) Trp. Now you can insert those in your formula and end up with an extinction coeffient of 21'890 M^-1 * cm^-1. This formula is only valid if all Cys are reduced (GFP has n=2 Cys that could form a disulfide bridge).

If you want to avoid all the formulas I suggest you copy the sequence of GFP and paste it into [ExPASy ProtParam](https://web.expasy.org/protparam/). This way you get a nice overview of the amino acid distribution of your protein and also retrieve the extinction coefficient under oxidizing conditions, which BTW is 22'015 M^-1 * cm^-1.